# Two groups for Radio Button in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

Hello I have the following Problem: I have a `DataTemplate` with `RadioButton`s and I want that each `RadioButton` functionally belongs to the two groups. Is this possible?

So I want that I can only click one Button in a row and one button in a column.

At the moment I can click a button twice in a column, but I can click every button in 1 row.

I found nothing helpful on Google.
Anyone got an Idea?

```
                   <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Hauptfoto</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton Foreground="DarkBlue" GroupName="HauptfotoRB" x:Name="HauptfotoRB" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0" Checked="HauptfotoRB_Checked"></RadioButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Oben__1</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton Foreground="DarkBlue" GroupName="ObenRB" x:Name="ObenRB" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0" Checked="ObenRB_Checked" ></RadioButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Innen__2</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton Foreground="DarkBlue" GroupName="InnenRB"  x:Name="InnenRB"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0" Checked="InnenRB_Checked" ></RadioButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `DataGrid` you could e.g. use second invisible `RadioButton` for the columns synchronization and `AlternationIndex` as row index for the row synchronization (if you have an ID by your row data, than of course it can be used instead of `AlternationIndex` for row synchronization) and do bind them with each other:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="col1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=b}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <RadioButton Name="b" 
                                        Content="SomeContent" 
                                        GroupName="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="col2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=b}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <RadioButton Name="b" 
                                        Content="SomeContent" 
                                        GroupName="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="col3" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=b}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <RadioButton Name="b" 
                                        Content="SomeContent" 
                                        GroupName="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```